# Top level domain order constraints

Tags: domain-name

Is there a specific order constraints in TLDs.

For example, Can a country code top level domain appear right before generic top level domains?

```
website.us.com
```

Can infrastructure tlds appear before generic tlds?

```
website.arpa.com
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what sorting and *before* constraint would apply to domains - apart from sorting them alphabetically which would be dependent on your platform and culture.

Comment: So there is no right and wrong way of ordering them?

Comment: *Right* or *wrong* is entirely up to an arbitrary order definition of your choice.